# Program that asks a multiple-choice question won't show the user an answer after an invalid character is entered

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program where the user has to answer a multiple choice question. The program works completely fine when the user enters A, B, C, or D. But if they enter "Z" for example, it stops working at a certain point. The program will proceed as prompted by saying "Invalid answer, please enter A, B, C, or D." But when you select A, B, C, or D, the program suddenly ends instead of showing whether or not the user was correct.

I tried to call the getAnswer() method again as the default case in the switch statement, so the program will ask the user for their choice again. Before I added this line, it didn't do that at all. However, it's still not following through with that last step. Here's the code:

```
// Call the method that will ask the user the question. 
        askQuestion();

        // Call the method that will allow the user to answer. 
        getAnswer();

        switch(userChoice)
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                    System.out.println("Incorrect! 'Switch' IS a key word. The correct answer was B. ");
                    System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                    System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                case 'c':
                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("Incorrect! 'Float' IS a key word. The correct answer was B. ");
                    System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                case 'd':
                case 'D':
                    System.out.println("Incorrect! 'True' IS a key word. The correct answer was B. ");
                    System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid character.");
                    // Repeats the getAnswer method to retrieve a valid character.
                    getAnswer();
            }   
    }

    // method that will ask the question
    public static void askQuestion()  
    {
        // Show the user the possible answers for the multiple choice questions.
        System.out.println("Which of these is NOT a Java key word?");
        System.out.println("A: switch");
        System.out.println("B: keyboard");
        System.out.println("C: float");
        System.out.println("D: true");
    }

    // method that will retrieve the answer from the user 
    public static char getAnswer()
    {
        // create another Scanner object
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Tell the user to select their answer and store it in a variable. 
        System.out.println("Select your answer by pressing A, B, C, or D.");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        userChoice = input.charAt(0);

        // Return the user's answer to main. 
        return userChoice;
    }
```

Ideally, if the user presses Z, but then presses A the next time around, it will tell the user is wrong, but the program is just ending instead of providing feedback. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to use a loop here.  You keep looping until the user enters a valid response:

```
askQuestion(); 

while (true) {

    userChoice = getAnswer();

    switch(userChoice)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            System.out.println("Incorrect! 'Switch' IS a key word. The correct answer was B. ");
            System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
            System.exit(0);

        ...

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid character.");
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need the **break** statements after each **System.exit(0)** call.

You could move the **askQuestion()** call inside the **while** loop if you wanted to re-ask the question on a bad input.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to use the case expression to verify if it is lowercase or uppercase, I recommend that you use the following:

```
String value = String.valueOf(userChoice).toUpperCase();
```

This helps to make the conversion of lowercase to uppercase before doing the evaluation in the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a recurring method call when an invalid answer is received

```
public void doProcess(){ //this will keep getting called until a valid key is read.

    askQuestion(); 
    userChoice = getAnswer();

    switch(userChoice)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A': 
            case 'b':
                //program will exit/ correct wrong ans etc etc 
                break;
            default: 
            //call itself again
            doProcess();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just did something similar to this and it worked!

Comment: @RachelWonder if the answer works for you, consider setting the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch case only checks for a single time only for the first answer.
You can have function for finidng the answer itself.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{

```
// method that will ask the question
public static void askQuestion()  
{
    // Show the user the possible answers for the multiple choice questions.
    System.out.println("Which of these is NOT a Java key word?");
    System.out.println("A: switch");
    System.out.println("B: keyboard");
    System.out.println("C: float");
    System.out.println("D: true");
}

// method that will retrieve the answer from the user 
public static char getAnswer()
{
    // create another Scanner object
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Tell the user to select their answer and store it in a variable. 
    System.out.println("Select your answer by pressing A, B, C, or D.");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    char userChoice = input.charAt(0);

    // Return the user's answer to main. 
    return userChoice;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {// Call the method that will ask the user the question. 
    askQuestion();

    // Call the method that will allow the user to answer. 
    char userChoice = getAnswer();

    while(!checkForCorrectAnswer(userChoice)){
        userChoice = getAnswer();
    }

}

private static boolean checkForCorrectAnswer(char userChoice){
    switch(userChoice)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                System.out.println("Incorrect! 'Switch' IS a key word. The correct answer was B. ");
                System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                System.out.println("Incorrect! 'Float' IS a key word. The correct answer was B. ");
                System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                System.out.println("Incorrect! 'True' IS a key word. The correct answer was B. ");
                System.out.println("The program will now end. Thanks for answering!");
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid character.");
                // Repeats the getAnswer method to retrieve a valid character.
                return false;
        }   
}
```

}